# It will displays blank in Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I am having an issue with App Script. So, I am currently finding a way in Google Sheet that if a user opens the Sheet, there will a pop-up UI that will display the Email they currently logged in. I tried this:
`function onOpen() { var userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(); var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); ui.alert('User Email', 'The current user\'s email is: ' + userEmail, ui.ButtonSet.OK); }`

But this will work only to the owner of the Google Sheet and the App Script. I shared a link to another email and when the UI won't display the email or return NULL. And when I give permissions of the App Script to that email, it's still won't work. The only time that this code will work on another email is that I will manually run the code. Is there something I missed? Tried ChatGBT btw but still nothing.

Comment: Google Workspace Domain Users: Scripts have broader access to user data, including email addresses, within the same Google Workspace domain.
For standard Gmail accounts, Google's privacy policies are stricter, often leading the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() method to return an empty string.